# Which web GUI / component frameworks, plugins and toolkits are available, that are based on jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tend to use jQuery because of jQuery UI, which is pretty nice. But unfortunately a lot of things are missing, like beautiful form components (i.e. autocompleting select-fields with search-string-input in the root, or multiselect fields with search, password fields with security strength checker, etc.)

I'd like to collect all frameworks and toolkits here, which are based on jQuery (for compatibility).

I start with:

- jQuery UI
- jQuery Toolkit

Comment: If this post is intended to aggregate a list of jQuery extensions, it is probably better when it's wiki'd.

Comment: how? I don't see any option here to make it a wiki. What I see is: edit|close|delete|flag, that's all... maybe someone else with more rep can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the [jQuery plugins page and filtering by Widgets](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/50)? Most, if not all, of the plugins for jQuery are registered there. Seems kind of pointless to create another list.